# how to get the id of the nth select box that is present in the n-th td of a tr using jquery

Tags: jquery

how to get the id of the nth select box that is present in the n-th td of a tr using jquery. Say, I want to obtain the `id` of the 4th select box that is present in the the 4th `<td>` of the `<tr>`.

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="tab_btn_segment">
        <td><select>
              <option></option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      <td><select id="popupSel">
              <option></option>
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
          </select>
      </td>
      <td><select>
            <option></option>
            <option>=</option>
            <option>> <</option>  
            <option>≧ ≦</option> 
            <option>≠</option> 
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><select id="popupSelChange">
            <option></option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Here I need to get `id="popupSelChange"` on a change event in jquery.

Comment: Share your HTML and Jquery code.

Comment: post the code that you have tried, we are not here to write for you form scratch. ;)

Comment: Did you try anything?  `$("tbody td[3] select[3]").attr("id")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `nth-child` like below

`$("tr td:nth-child(4) select").attr("id")`

**As you have said you need an `change` on id `#popupSelChange` ao can use directly as below because ID is unique for every element.**

```
$("#popupSelChange").change(
   // Your Code

);
```